# can developer pro sandbox copy production data?

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

Hi I have a developer pro sandbox in my org, i would like to know if I refresh it will i able to copy data from my production to this sandbox environment?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only custom settings and Product data will be copied over automatically. Remaining objects will have to be loaded via data loader

Comment: how about my existing data in my sandbox?  will refresh wipe out all my existing data in my sandbox?

Comment: @user2074703, It does not copy standard/custom object records so refresh will not wipe out your existing data in sandbox.

Comment: Sethu is incorrect. A sandbox refresh will wipe any non-setup data (excluding that stated by HSG).

Answer (score 4):

When you create a new developer or developer pro sandbox, Salesforce doesn't copy the data over for most objects (just the core objects like User, RecordType, etc.). If you want to populate the sandbox with data, I suggest using an app like SFXOrgData (http://www.sfApex.com) to accomplish this. I developed this application about 2 years ago exactly for this purpose.

Before this, I (and everyone else) had to create and maintain a bunch of Excel spreadsheets which did VLOOKUPS on the Id fields to remap everything in order to maintain the relationships between records. Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 0):

Developer sandboxes are meant for coding and testing. These environments include a copy of your production organization’s metadata, or Setup data. It does not include any data from custom or standard objects. If the data was present, it will wipe out the data.

Developer Pro have a larger storage limit than Developer sandboxes. This enables you to handle more development and quality assurance tasks. Developer Pro sandboxes should be used for integrated testing.

I always reference this page for the complete guide to [Salesforce sandboxes](http://www.flosum.com/definitive-guide-salesforce-sandboxes/).